# How can I repair the lower sash of a window

Tags: windows

How do I find parts for a window, Been to several stores like Lowes, Home Depot, ace etc  I am looking for a part that looks like this. it's for holding 
the lower sash of the window to stay up when open[image]

Answer (score 1):

- whittle something out of wood
- identify the manufacturer and ask them
- use it as an excuse to buy a 3-d printer.
- ditto forge, casting sand, aluminium etc
- ditto clapped-out Bridgeport ...

Comment: Ah, the ubiquitous clapped-out Bridgeport, for when the solution needs to be extra skookum.